# Facebook public posts I make using the Open Graph API are not seen by friends

Tags: facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api

I'm making a simple Facebook app that posts updates to the user's timeline using node.js and Facebook's Open Graph API. Even though *I* can see the posts I make using the OG API on *my* timeline (and it has the globe icon identifying that it's a public post, see pic below), none in my FB friend network can see it.

Here's a screenie of a public post I made via OG API showing up on my timeline, along with a post from a 3rd party app (Pool practice) for comparison:

[image][image]

Now here's the screenie of my friend's timeline showing only the Pool Practice post, the post from my app is nowhere to be seen...
[image]

---

I've checked the app settings and permissions as well as the OG API options, but haven't seen anything that points to how I can solve this problem. Here's the node.js code I'm using to post the updates:

```
    // app permissions set to 'publish_actions' and 'publish_stream'
    // I do the auth dance here to get the access_token and store it in session as fb_token


    var request = require( 'superagent' ); // module from TJ Holowaychuk similar to "request"
request
    .post( 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=' + req.session.fb_token )
    .send( { message: 'posting via node.js' } )
    .set( 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' )
    .end( function( response ) {
        log( response );
    });
```

The code above works and the post shows up on *my* timeline, but no one else is able to see it.
Anyone know a way out of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to submit each action for Facebook validation before your friends can view it. Only users defined as developpers for the app are allowed to view those timeline messages.

[image: Hit the submit link]

Comment: I have to do some changes before I can submit my action for approval and know for certain if that was what the problem was, but I think you nailed it. I don't see how else it can work perfectly in my timeline but not in others. Thank you, you saved me a bunch of my time, been looking to sort this out for a few days now.

Comment: update: Instead of waiting for the approval process, I've added my friend who couldn't see the post as a "developer". Now if he's able to see the posts, we have confirmed the cause.